# Downgrade SonarQube from 6.2 to 6.1

Tags: sonarqube

Can someone help me with some documentation on how to downgrade the SonarQube from Version 6.2 to Version 6.1 without loosing the existing analysis data?

Comment: Without a DB backup, this is not possible. Why do you want to downgrade?

Comment: I have installed 6.2 version but could find features which are required for me like filtering the projects based on custom measures. So thought i will downgrade for now and upgrade to the next version once the Tagging feature is available for projects in SonarQube

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your feedback! So I will just give an answer below about the impossibility to downgrade w/o a DB backup.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to downgrade properly is to start over from a DB backup that you (hopefully) made prior to the upgrade of SonarQube.